# Adding path to resource for WSO2 APIM web socket

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

If my websocket production endpoint is `ws://example.com/test/plugins/token=<access token>`, is that possible to use the web socket API on WSO2 API manager to map this? Seems that path to resource is not available in WSO2 APIM. If I just map ws://example.com and add the path to resource at the back of given WS URL by APIM, it won't work.

I need to have different token for ws to work.

The example given here has not path to resource:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+a+WebSocket+API